# Change radiobutton's font color using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have a radio button list, default style. It is used to indicate response type to a question typed by an admin user (single line text, multi-line text, calendar, etc.). Once question is added I provide Edit/Delete buttons for it. When Edit is clicked I wanted to highlight the selected option (change its color to red) so as to provide user with a visually indication of what option this question is associated with and also to allow user to pick a different option (If I check the selected option, user won't be able to click it again).

In edit mode I provide Save and Cancel. In either case I want to use jQuery to reset the font color back to black but can't see how to get it to work.

```
protected void EditQuestion()
{
    // I removed bunch of other stuff that populate other controls
    string sResponseTypeID = "some value";
    rblResponseType.ClearSelection();
    ListItem li = rblResponseType.Items.FindByValue(sResponseTypeID);

    if (null != li)
    {
        li.Attributes.Add("style", "color: red");
        //li.Selected = true;
    }
}


// Trying to reset the color back to black
function clearEdit() {debugger
    var respTypeID = $("#hfRespTypeID").val();
    $this = $(":radio[value=" + respTypeID + "]");
    $this.css('color', 'black');

    //$('[name="rblResponseType"]').removeAttr('style');
    //$("input[name=rblResponseType][value=" + respTypeID + "]").attr('style', 'color:green');
}
```

Comment: Why not remove the style attribute again?

Comment: I tried to remove the attribute but didn't work and I commented it out. See the commented out section in jQuery function.

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). (Please include the html.)